# How to get the dataframe out of a json format

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here, i have a json format data, I wanted to get particular values as my column name, and the respective values.

DATA:

```
{
"552783667052167168": {
    "552783667052167168": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "France: 10 people dead after shooting at HQ of satirical weekly newspaper #CharlieHebdo, according to witnesses ",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": 552783667052167168,


        }

    "552785374507175936": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "MT @euronews France: 10 dead after shooting at HQ of satirical weekly #CharlieHebdo. If Zionists/Jews did this they'd be nuking Israel",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552783667052167168,
        "id": 552785374507175936,

        }
    "552786226546495488": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "@j0nathandavis They who? Stupid and partial opinions like this one only add noise to any debate.",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552785374507175936,
        "id": 552786226546495488
        }
    }
"552791196247269378": {
    "552791196247269378": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "BREAKING: At least 10 killed in shooting at French satirical newspaper Charlie Hebdo, Paris prosecutor's office says. ,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": 552791196247269378
        }
    "552791516360765440": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "@cnni 11 Killed now",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552791196247269378,
        "id": 552791516360765440
        }
    "552791567401238529": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "@cnni 11 died",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552791196247269378,
        "id": 552791567401238529
        }
    }
```

I wanted to have the respective columns mainID, and text as my columns.
There is one thing which is completed here is the first ID which is `552783667052167168` also has a text, if you see the format,  `{
        "552783667052167168": {
            "552783667052167168": {` 
so this will be my mainID, and the respective  text as main text, and we build another two columns for the childs.

output:

```
ParentID           parentText              ChildID         childText
552783667052167168 "France: 10 people dead 552785374507175936 "MT @euronews France: 10 dead after
552783667052167168 "France: 10 people dead 552786226546495488 "@j0nathandavis They who? 
552791196247269378  "BREAKING: At least 10 killed  552791516360765440 "@cnni 11 Killed now"
552791196247269378  "BREAKING: At least 10 killed  552791567401238529  "@cnni 11 died"
```

Here, we will have `"in_reply_to_status_id": null` as null if its a parent ID. I guess we can use this as a rule.

Edit one :

I was able to code it until here, but, the source tweet's text is still coming.

```
for sourceTweet, tweets in dataTrain.items():
    #print(sourceTweet)
    for tweet, tweetContent in tweets.items():
        #print(tweet)
        for iTweet, iTweetContent in tweets.items():
            #print(iTweet)
            if (sourceTweet==iTweet):
                sourceTweetContent = iTweetContent
                sourceTweetText = iTweetContent["text"]
                break
        for jTweet, jTweetContent in tweets.items():
            #print(jTweet)
            if (tweetContent["in_reply_to_status_id"]==jTweet):
                replyToTweetContent = jTweetContent
                replyToTweetText = jTweetContent["text"]
                print(replyToTweetText)
                break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!!

```
a = """{
"552783667052167168": {
    "552783667052167168": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "France: 10 people dead after shooting at HQ of satirical weekly newspaper #CharlieHebdo, according to witnesses",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": 552783667052167168
        },
    "552785374507175936": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "MT @euronews France: 10 dead after shooting at HQ of satirical weekly #CharlieHebdo. If Zionists/Jews did this they'd be nuking Israel",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552783667052167168,
        "id": 552785374507175936
        },
    "552786226546495488": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "@j0nathandavis They who? Stupid and partial opinions like this one only add noise to any debate.",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552785374507175936,
        "id": 552786226546495488
        }
    },
"552791196247269378": {
    "552791196247269378": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "BREAKING: At least 10 killed in shooting at French satirical newspaper Charlie Hebdo, Paris prosecutor's office says." ,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": 552791196247269378
        },
    "552791516360765440": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "@cnni 11 Killed now",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552791196247269378,
        "id": 552791516360765440
        },
    "552791567401238529": {
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "@cnni 11 died",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552791196247269378,
        "id": 552791567401238529
        }
    }
}"""
```

**Code**

```
data = json.loads(a)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ParentId','parentText','ChildId','childText'])

l = []
pos = 0
for a in data:
    for d in data[a]:
        if d == a:
            l.append(a)
            l.append(data[a][d]['text'])
        else:
            l.append(d)
            l.append(data[a][d]['text'])
            df.loc[pos] = l
            l.remove(d)
            l.remove(data[a][d]['text'])
            pos+=1
    l = []
```

**Output**

```
             ParentId                                         parentText  \
0  552783667052167168  France: 10 people dead after shooting at HQ of...   
1  552783667052167168  France: 10 people dead after shooting at HQ of...   
2  552791196247269378  BREAKING: At least 10 killed in shooting at Fr...   
3  552791196247269378  BREAKING: At least 10 killed in shooting at Fr...   

              ChildId                                          childText  
0  552785374507175936  MT @euronews France: 10 dead after shooting at...  
1  552786226546495488  @j0nathandavis They who? Stupid and partial op...  
2  552791516360765440                                @cnni 11 Killed now  
3  552791567401238529                                      @cnni 11 died
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, maybe not the most elegant way, but its a solution. Hope it helps:

```
# get the parent keys
parentkeys = list(json.keys())

# create lists to fill for columns later
parentids = []
childids = []
contributors = []
truncated = []
text = []
in_reply_to_status_id = []
id =[]

# get the data out the json
for parentkey in parentkeys:
    for child in json[parentkey]:
        parentids.append(parentkey)
        childids.append(child)
        contributors.append(json[parentkey][child]['contributors'])
        truncated.append(json[parentkey][child]['truncated'])
        text.append(json[parentkey][child]['text'])
        in_reply_to_status_id.append(json[parentkey][child]['in_reply_to_status_id'])
        id.append(json[parentkey][child]['id'])

# create the dataframe out the of the lists        
df = pd.DataFrame({'ParentID':parentids,
                   'ChildID':childids,
                   'contributors':contributors,
                   'truncated':truncated,
                   'text':text,
                   'in_reply_to_status_id':in_reply_to_status_id,
                   'id':id})
```

So now we have to transform the `dataframe` in the format you asked:

```
# copy the text as parent text if it doenst have a child id
df['parentText'] = np.where(df.in_reply_to_status_id == 'null', df.text, None)

# fill the rows below untill you hit a different value rowwise
df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=0, inplace=True)

# filter the rows which have the same parent and childid
df = df[df.ParentID != df.ChildID]

# rename the column to the name which was asked
df.rename(columns={'text':'childText'}, inplace=True)

# select the 4 columns which are needed
df = df[['ParentID', 'parentText', 'ChildID', 'childText']]
```

**Output**

```
    ParentID            parentText                                        ChildID    childText
1   552783667052167168  France: 10 people dead after shooting at HQ of... 552785374507175936    MT @euronews France: 10 dead after shooting at...
2   552783667052167168  France: 10 people dead after shooting at HQ of...   552786226546495488  @j0nathandavis They who? Stupid and partial op...
4   552791196247269378  BREAKING: At least 10 killed in shooting at Fr...   552791516360765440  @cnni 11 Killed now
5   552791196247269378  BREAKING: At least 10 killed in shooting at Fr...   552791567401238529  @cnni 11 died
```

**EDIT**
Your json gave errors in my console. I cleaned it up for you, please use this to test:

```
json = {
"552783667052167168": {
    "552783667052167168": {
        "contributors": "null",
        "truncated": "false",
        "text": "France: 10 people dead after shooting at HQ of satirical weekly newspaper #CharlieHebdo, according to witnesses",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": "null",
        "id": 552783667052167168

        },
    "552785374507175936": {
        "contributors": "null",
        "truncated": "false",
        "text": "MT @euronews France: 10 dead after shooting at HQ of satirical weekly #CharlieHebdo. If Zionists/Jews did this they'd be nuking Israel",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552783667052167168,
        "id": 552785374507175936

        },
    "552786226546495488": {
        "contributors": "null",
        "truncated": "false",
        "text": "@j0nathandavis They who? Stupid and partial opinions like this one only add noise to any debate.",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552785374507175936,
        "id": 552786226546495488
        }
    },
"552791196247269378": {
    "552791196247269378": {
        "contributors": "null",
        "truncated": "false",
        "text": "BREAKING: At least 10 killed in shooting at French satirical newspaper Charlie Hebdo, Paris prosecutor's office says.",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": "null",
        "id": 552791196247269378
        },
    "552791516360765440": {
        "contributors": "null",
        "truncated": "false",
        "text": "@cnni 11 Killed now",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552791196247269378,
        "id": 552791516360765440
        },
    "552791567401238529": {
        "contributors": "null",
        "truncated": "false",
        "text": "@cnni 11 died",
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 552791196247269378,
        "id": 552791567401238529
        }
    }
}
```